# Cannot acess data from Eloquent: Relationships, as well some data is not retrieved

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I want to show my data from relation between tables in my view, where the relations are:

- Curso   1 --- * Disciplina.
- Disciplina * -- 1 Professor.

All the 3 tables have the field 'nome'

The page in View will show:

- The field 'nome' of table 'Curso'.
- A HTML table with 2 column:

  - The field 'nome' of table 'Disciplina'.
  - The field 'nome' of table 'Professor'.

But I'm having 2 problems:

1. I get the data of 'Disciplina' that I need, but some of them don't show the data of associated 'Professor'.
2. I got a error when I try to access the field 'nome' of 'Professor' from the 'Disciplina' when I try to list it in the table.

My 'Disciplina' Model

```
public function professor(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Professor','id');
}
```

My Controller

```
$curso = Curso::find($id);
$curso->disciplinas();

foreach ($curso->disciplinas as $key => $disciplina) {
    $disciplina->professor;
}

return View::make('curso.showCurso')->with('curso', $curso);
```

My table in View

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($curso->disciplinas as $key => $disciplina)
        <tr>
            <td> {{$disciplina->nome}} </td>
            <td> {{$disciplina->professor}} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

This image show part of the table, where the first row are not showing the professor and the remaining rows are showing all fields from professor.

[Table showing all fields of 'professor'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xk5F.png)

When I try to show the field 'nome' of 'Professor' I change the code for:

```
<td> {{$disciplina->professor->nome}} </td>
```

But when I do it I get this error **"Trying to get property of non-object"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is incorrect:

```
public function professor(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Professor','id');
}
```

If `disciplinas` table contains the foreign key `professor_id`, then the relationship should simply be:

```
public function professor(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Professor');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now that I look, I don't even know why did I put 'id' as foreign_key.

I would set your answer as useful as well, but I cannot, I can just accept it.